# Make digraph edge arrow follow node pen width

Tags: graphviz

I would like to increase the border width of my nodes, but I find that the arrow heads in digraph edges do not respect the added width. Instead, they sink into the border. Here's my simple graph.

```
strict digraph  {
    a [penwidth="10.0"];
    b [penwidth="10.0"];
    a -> b;
}
```

[image: bad arrow head]

How could I either increase the node width safely, or distance the edges further back? Reading through the [attribute list](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html), I didn't find a way. The closest was `peripheries`, but it makes multiple narrow peripheries instead of a thick one, but the edges do stick to the outermost periphery.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://forum.graphviz.org/t/allign-nodes-stroke-with-end-of-the-arrows-path-width/462

The only work-around I know is to "move" **node b** or shorten the edge - described in the bug report.

Comment: I see! Thanks a bunch for the information. I think I'll wait for it to be fixed then, seeing it has been reported fairly recently. Are you a contributor? If so, are you aware of a corresponding ticket on the [issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues)? I didn't see one created at a similar time as the forum post. Should one be created?